# Laravel Blade Count Rows

Tags: laravel-5, relationship, laravel-blade

I could really use some guidance; I'm trying to count the number of rows where the

> table field value = $someValue

and

> echo the count

.

How could I accomplish this?

Somthing like this:

```
 @foreach($setas as $seta)

      <tr>
          <td>{{ $seta->name }}</td>
          <td>{{  $seta->staffaccred::where('status','=',1)->count() }}</td>                    
     </tr>

  @endforeach
```

Comment: Why don't you use has many and make count using active record in model?

Comment: or post here both table fields so that solution can be written according to them

Comment: They have a hasMany relationship i found a solution eventually will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the count i needed using this:

`{{  count($seta->staffaccred->where('column', 'value')) }}`

```
@foreach($setas as $seta)

           <tr>
               <td>{{ $seta->name }}</td>
               <td>{{  count($seta->staffaccred->where('status', 'Expired')) }}</td>
           </tr>

    @endforeach
```